# Add dynamic custom buttons as array in summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, summernote

I use the wysiwyg editor "summernote" and codeigniter. I want add my own buttons to the toolbar that insert spezific text on click. That scenario is describes in the [summernote documentation](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#custom-button).

Summernote:

```
$('#model_txt').summernote({
    height: 250,

    toolbar: [
        ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
        ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
        ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
        ['color', ['color']],
        ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
        ['height', ['height']]
    ]
});
```

But i get the button names respectively the text that insert on click from a database. I get the data with an ajax call that call a PHP function that print the data from the query.

AJAX call:

```
var all_vars = null;

$.ajax({url: "get_vars", success: function(result){
     all_vars = result.split(";");
});
```

Now i have an array that contains the names (example: `all_vars[0]`).
But i don't know how can i insert the names as buttons in the toolbar... can you help me?

---

Can't anybody help me? I try this with the JS function eval() and it works but i think its not the best solution...

The PHP function on "127.0.0.1/create_var_buttons" create the JS code dynamicly.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var resturl = 'http://127.0.0.1/create_var_buttons';

    $.ajax({
        url: resturl,
        success: function(data){
            eval(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same need before and done this way:

- I had to declare a variable to hold the summernote's toolbar array:

  var toolbar = [
      ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['insert', ['picture', 'link']],
      ['misc', ['undo', 'redo', 'codeview']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['fontsize', ['fontsize', 'height']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['forecolor', ['forecolor']],
      ['custom', ['forcarJustificar']]
  ];
- Another to hold the data to summernotes's "buttons" property:

  var opt_btns_custom = {
          forcarJustificar: forcarJustificar
      };
- Another variable to hold the entire summernote's options:

  var sm_options = {
      height: altura,
      toolbar: toolbar,
      buttons: opt_btns_custom,
      callbacks: {}
  }
- Then I wrote the function below that I call into the Ajax's .done() for each button that need to be created:

  function addBtnText(b_content, b_tooltip, text) {

  ```
  var sm_botao_custom = function (context) {
      var ui = $.summernote.ui;

      options = {
          contents: b_content,
          tooltip: b_tooltip,
          click: function () {
              context.invoke('editor.insertText', text);
          }
      }

      var button = ui.button(options);

      return button.render();
  }

  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

  toolbar.push(['custom', ['sm_botao_custom_'+i]]);

  opt_btns_custom['sm_botao_custom_'+i] = sm_botao_custom;

  //Restart SM to apply the created buttons
  $('#d_summernote').summernote('destroy');
  $('#d_summernote').summernote(sm_options);
  ```

  }

OBS: I use a random number (i) to avoid conflict problems with the buttons inside the SM.